# Nil vs RecordNotFound for a failed query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When I do

```
User.find_by_username('some_user')
```

and it fails to find the user the above query returns nil.  However,

```
User.find(1)
```

throws an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error if it fails to find the user.  The rails guide says this is supposed to happen but doesn't explain why. That's my question, why are there two different behaviors?  Thanks!

Comment: For consistence, use find_by_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound is raised only when record with given id(s) is not found.

If you don't want the exception when searching by id, you can use:

```
User.find_by_id('foo')
```

The difference to me is:

1. User.find: get me that user.
2. User.find_by_foo('foo'): is there a user with foo == foo?

The first (1) assumes existence of your record so failure should raise an exception.

The second (2) assumes you want to query the existence of your record so missing record results to nil.